# Where does the extra mass come from in a high-mass morph?

Tags: animorphs, z-space, morphing

So, in [Animorphs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Animorphs), the kids gain the ability to morph into any animal they can touch.  For the most part, the exact mechanics are hand-waved due to it being magic-like alien technology, but one in particular was not.

When they morph into anything, their mass also changes.  They do not become a 150-pound mosquito, for example.  And in book 12, [The Reaction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Reaction_%28Animorphs%29), Rachel "burps" a full-grown crocodile, all that mass coming from... somewhere.

Normally this wouldn't bother me too much; [Applied Phlebotinum](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/AppliedPhlebotinum) <sup>(TVTropes)</sup> doesn't need explanation.  However, in book 18, [The Decision](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Decision_%28Animorphs%29), we get a direct look at at least one of the mechanics behind how the morphing power works:

When using a low-mass morph, the extra mass is extruded into Z-Space (a parallel dimension mostly used for faster-than-light communication and travel), then retrieved when the morpher returns to their natural form.

What I don't recall is whether or not it's ever explained where the extra mass from a *high*-mass morph comes from - such as when Rachel becomes an elephant, or when that crocodile was created.

The best I could find so far is an (unsourced) Word of God joke from TVTropes - on the [ShapeshifterBaggage](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/ShapeshifterBaggage) page:

> Applegate explained once that it came from "Black holes, and pygmy hippos."

Is that really the only explanation out there, and is it a real quote?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Okay, apparently I just don't have *quite* enough patience sometimes.  After filtering through a bunch of Youtube results for pygmies, I found [this page of questions/answers by K. A. Applegate](http://www.hiracdelest.com/database/articles/according/1999/accord_april99.htm), one of which was:

> You know how when the Animorphs morph into smaller animals their body mass goes into Zero-Space. Well where do they get the body mass when they morph into big animals????????????
>   Your #1 fan,
>   A.J.

With the answer:

> Hi, A.J.
>   Additional body mass is actually drawn from NFL players who graciously donate . . . No? Okay, try this: additional body mass is drawn directly from a herd of hippopotomi, which, of course, explains the existence of pygmy hippos. Or not. Okay, here's the real answer: **black holes suck mass into and through z-space. A certain amount of mass is thus always in transit through z-space and can be drawn into the vacuum created by morphing a large animal.** Go ahead, try that out on your physics teacher and see if he/she buys it.
>   --KAA

So I guess the joke on TVTropes is half correct - Applegate said something like that, but also said technobabble that works well enough:  Stuff sucked into a black hole is in transit through Z-Space, and can be indirectly "borrowed" for those high-mass morphs.

Comment: Z-space is pretty much the handwave explanation for anything impossible in the Animorphs setting. "Q: In Animorphs, how does X? A: Z-space." It's the equivalent of "A wizard did it."

Comment: @BrianS And in Animorphs, the wizard is also the Ellimist.